# Scroll with multiple, and going different directions

Tags: jquery, html

I have a large image of an L-shaped painting on one page. I created divs over parts of the painting I want to explain. When the page loads, I want it to scroll down the length of the image, and then move to the left of the image, stopping at each div for a few seconds. I understand how to get the page to scroll down on load, but I do not understand how to continue scrolling once it has reached the first div. Should I target the data-box and not the class, so it will continue to move through each div box?

```
        <div class=" box totem">
            <span class="hoverTotem" data-box="totem" ></span>
        </div>


    <!-- ganesh -->
    <div class="focus box ganesh">
        <span data-box="ganesh" ></span>
    </div>
    <!-- BIRD 1 -->
    <div class="box bird1">
        <span data-box="bird1" ></span>
    </div>
    <!-- KATY -->
    <div class="box katy">
        <span data-box="katy" ></span>
    </div>
    <!-- FREDIA -->
    <div class="box fredia">
        <span data-box="fredia" ></span>
    </div>   

    <!-- saar -->
    <div class="box saar">
        <span data-box="saar" ></span>
    </div>

    <!-- parks -->
    <div class="box parks">
        <span data-box="parks" ></span>
    </div>

    <!-- james -->
    <div class="box james">
        <span data-box="james" ></span>
    </div> 

    <!-- ANNA -->
    <div class="box anna">
        <span data-box="anna" ></span>
    </div>  

    <!-- ANDY -->
    <div class="box andy">
        <span data-box="andy" ></span>
    </div> 

    <!-- AI -->
    <div class="box ai">
        <span data-box="ai" ></span>
    </div>

    <!-- FRIENDS -->
    <div class="box friends1">
        <span data-box="friends1" ></span>
    </div>
    <div class="friends2">
        <span data-box="friends2" ></span>
    </div>
    <div class="box friends3">
        <span data-box="friends3" ></span>
    </div>  

    <!-- KIDS -->
    <div class="box kids">
        <span data-box="kids" ></span>
    </div>          
    <!-- PARENTS -->    
    <div class="box parents">
        <span data-box="parents" ></span>
    </div>          
    <!-- QUOTE -->    
    <div class="box quote">
        <span data-box="quote" ></span>
    </div>      
    <!-- BIRD 2 -->
    <div class="box bird2">
        <span data-box="box bird2" ></span>
    </div>        
</div>



<div class="container-fluid">
    <div id="" class="row meaningImg">
        <div class="background">                        
            <a href="../public/img/TALLPART1.png">
              <img class="" src="../public/img/TALLPART1.png" class="meaningImg">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>      

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(".bird1").offset().top}, 5000),
        scrollLeft: $('.quote').offset().top}, 5000);
});


</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got my code to work.

I kept my HTML the same but made a few changes to my jQuery.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(".ganesh").offset().top,
}, 5000).animate({
    scrollLeft: $(".bird1").offset().left,
}, 5000).animate({
    scrollLeft: $(".saar").offset().left,
}, 5000).animate({
     scrollLeft: $(".anna").offset().left,
}, 5000).animate({
     scrollLeft: $(".friends1").offset().left,
}, 5000).animate({
     scrollLeft: $(".quote").offset().left,
}, 5000);
});
```